# Generate a random float between 0 and 1

Tags: ios, c, random, floating-point, arc4random

I'm trying to generate a random number that's between 0 and 1. I keep reading about `arc4random()`, but there isn't any information about getting a float from it. How do I do this?

Comment: Not duplicates, this appears to be the only question explicitly pertaining to floats.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Random value in **[0, 1[** (including 0, excluding 1):

```
double val = ((double)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX);
```

A bit more details [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010223916/http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com:80/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html).

Actual range is **[0, 0.999999999767169356]**, as upper bound is (double)0xFFFFFFFF / 0x100000000.

Comment: Thank You. Most straight forward answer I have seen. I will read up on your link and get additional details on this. Thanks again.

Comment: It's weird that `ARC4RANDOM_MAX` has to be manually defined, but [`0x100000000` is 4294967296](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=0x100000000+in+decimal), which is [`ULONG_MAX + 1`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/). Where is it documented that `arc4random()`'s max is `ULONG_MAX` anyhow?

Comment: @bobobobo, from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1

Comment: @bobobobo, although I agree that defining constant for this case does not look nice

Comment: Actually, the value should be 0xFFFFFFFF, (2**32)-1 == 0x100000000 - 0x1 == 0xFFFFFFFF == UINT32_MAX as currently stated by Jörg Bühmann on the link.

Comment: @Vladimir, What type is `ARC4RANDOM_MAX`? I want to define it as a variable.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, you can declare it as unsigned long.

Comment: Values generated such a way are not guaranteed to be uniformly distributed!

Comment: @Josejulio, you're right, I've made a separate answer using `UINT32_MAX`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34765674/1033581

Answer (score 107):

```
// Seed (only once)
srand48(time(0));

double x = drand48();

// Swift version
// Seed (only once)
srand48(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))

let x = drand48()
```

> The drand48() and erand48() functions return non-negative, double-precision, floating-point values, uniformly distributed over the interval [0.0 , 1.0].

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: You maybe need to update just a little the answer, I [read on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/random/#random-double-between-0-and-1) that `drand48` need to be initialized once with a seed. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/srand48.3.html) also suggest that it should be initialized.

Comment: Seed is needed because it gives this random generator a starting point for calculations. Without it random sequence would always be the same across app launches.

Comment: This IS the best answer.

Comment: This answer is not an optimal precision answer for a `double`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765674/1033581 on how to achieve best precision.

Comment: I also think drand48() is fastest among all versions.

Answer (score 15):

**For Swift 4.2+ see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50733095/1033581**

---

Below are recommendations for correct uniformity and optimal precision for ObjC and Swift 4.1.

## 32 bits precision (Optimal for `Float`)

Uniform random value in **[0, 1]** (including 0.0 and 1.0), up to 32 bits precision:

**Obj-C**:

```
float val = (float)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX;
```

**Swift**:

```
let val = Float(arc4random()) / Float(UInt32.max)
```

It's optimal for:

- a `Float` (or `Float32`) which has a significand precision of 24 bits for its mantissa

## 48 bits precision (discouraged)

It's easy to achieve 48 bits precision with `drand48` ([which uses `arc4random_buf` under the hood](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/drand48.c)). But note that [drand48 has flaws](https://huxtable.ca/posts/2016/05/06/The-Problem-With-Rand.html) because of the seed requirement and also for being suboptimal to randomize all 52 bits of Double mantissa.

Uniform random value in **[0, 1]**, 48 bits precision:

**Swift**:

```
// seed (only needed once)
srand48(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))
// random Double value
let val = drand48()
```

## 64 bits precision (Optimal for `Double` and `Float80`)

Uniform random value in **[0, 1]** (including 0.0 and 1.0), up to 64 bits precision:

**Swift**, using two calls to arc4random:

```
let arc4random64 = UInt64(arc4random()) << 32 &+ UInt64(arc4random())
let val = Float80(arc4random64) / Float80(UInt64.max)
```

**Swift**, using one call to arc4random_buf:

```
var arc4random64: UInt64 = 0
arc4random_buf(&arc4random64, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: arc4random64))
let val = Float80(arc4random64) / Float80(UInt64.max)
```

It's optimal for:

- a `Double` (or `Float64`) which has a significand precision of 52 bits for its mantissa
- a `Float80` which has a significand precision of 64 bits for its mantissa

---

## Notes

#### Comparisons with other methods

Answers where the range is excluding one of the bounds (0 or 1) likely suffer from a uniformity bias and should be avoided.

- using `arc4random()`, best precision is 1 / 0xFFFFFFFF (UINT32_MAX)
- using `arc4random_uniform()`, best precision is 1 / 0xFFFFFFFE (UINT32_MAX-1)
- using `rand()` ([secretly using arc4random](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/rand.c)), best precision is 1 / 0x7FFFFFFF (RAND_MAX)
- using `random()` ([secretly using arc4random](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/random.c)), best precision is 1 / 0x7FFFFFFF (RAND_MAX)

It's mathematically impossible to achieve better than 32 bits precision with a single call to `arc4random`, `arc4random_uniform`, `rand` or `random`. So our above 32 bits and 64 bits solutions should be the best we can achieve.

Comment: 'Float80' is unavailable on real iOS devices (it only works on simulator).

Answer (score 10):

This function works for negative float ranges as well:

```
float randomFloat(float Min, float Max){
    return ((arc4random()%RAND_MAX)/(RAND_MAX*1.0))*(Max-Min)+Min;
}
```

Comment: Extraneous modulus operation.  use `Min+(Max-Min)*((float)arc4random())/ULONG_MAX` instead.  The `(float)` cast is just paranoia.

Comment: @bobobobo while I agree on the extraneous modulus, I advice to divide by UINT32_MAX (4294967295 always) instead of ULONG_MAX (18446744073709551615 on 64 bits).

Answer (score 7):

#### Swift 4.2+

Swift 4.2 adds native support for a random value in a Range:

```
let x = Float.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
let y = Double.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
let z = Float80.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
```

Doc:

- [`random(in range: ClosedRange<Float>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/2995566-random)
- [`random(in range: Range<Float>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/2995568-random)
- [`random(in range: ClosedRange<Double>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2995407-random)
- [`random(in range: Range<Double>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2995409-random)
- [`random(in range: ClosedRange<Float80>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float80/2999400-random)
- [`random(in range: Range<Float80>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float80/2999402-random)

Answer (score 1):

```
(float)rand() / RAND_MAX
```

The previous post stating "rand()" alone was incorrect.
This is the correct way to use rand().

This will create a number between 0 -> 1

> BSD docs:
>
> The rand() function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the
>   range of 0 to RAND_MAX (as defined by the header file "stdlib.h").

Answer (score 1):

This is extension for Float random number **Swift 3.1**

```
// MARK: Float Extension

public extension Float {

    /// Returns a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.
    public static var random: Float {
        return Float(arc4random()) / Float(UInt32.max))
    }

    /// Random float between 0 and n-1.
    ///
    /// - Parameter n:  Interval max
    /// - Returns:      Returns a random float point number between 0 and n max
    public static func random(min: Float, max: Float) -> Float {
        return Float.random * (max - min) + min
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cœur Thanks you i change that

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

Swift 4.2 has included a native and fairly full-featured random number API in the standard library. ([Swift Evolution proposal SE-0202](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md))

```
let intBetween0to9 = Int.random(in: 0...9) 
let doubleBetween0to1 = Double.random(in: 0...1)
```

All number types have the static [random(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2995514-random) function which takes the range and returns the random number in the given range.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to avoid problems with upper bound of *arc4random()*

```
u_int32_t upper_bound = 1000000;

float r = arc4random_uniform(upper_bound)*1.0/upper_bound;
```

Note that it is applicable for MAC_10_7, IPHONE_4_3 and higher.

Comment: There is a fundamental range issue with this. It's easily noticeable when you set upper_bound to 10, arc4random_uniform will return values from 0 to 9, and final result will be from 0.0000 to 0.9000. You should instead divide by `upper_bound-1`. Yet, you would still have an arbitrarily low precision caused by upper_bound, so you should increase the upper_bound to UINT32_MAX. And you can get even better precision from using `arc4random()*1.0 / UINT32_MAX` instead of `arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX)*1.0 / (UINT32_MAX-1)`.

Answer (score -1):

`arc4random` has a range up to 0x100000000 (4294967296)

This is another good option to generate random numbers between 0 to 1:

```
srand48(time(0));      // pseudo-random number initializer.
double r = drand48();
```

Comment: arc4random max value is 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: Thanks @Cœur ..max val 0xFFFFFFFF i wasn't know

Comment: your solution is also identical to Jovan Stankovic answer.

Comment: Ohh i didn't saw that @Cœur

Answer (score -4):

```
float x = arc4random() % 11 * 0.1;
```

That produces a random float bewteen 0 and 1.
[More info here](http://46media.net/xcode-turorials/how-to-generate-a-random-float-between-0-and-1-in-objective-c-xcode/)

Comment: Note: only gives 11 discrete values: 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0

Comment: Yes, the modulus operation cuts arc4random()'s result to being between 0 and 10, then he divides it by 10. This answer is really bad for general use.

Answer (score -4):

```
rand()
```

by default produces a random number(float) between 0 and 1.

Comment: This produces a random int for me.

Comment: `rand()` doesn't [seem to exist on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=rand), and if it did, it would produce an integer like it does on every other *NIX.

Comment: @JoshCaswell `rand()` is part of C, which is in turn part of Objective-C (which is used in iOS programming). C functions like `rand()` absolutely exist on iOS, but `arc4random()` is preferred.