# Random number frame.origin.x

Tags: objective-c

I want a random `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y` on each button click. The button need's to move inside of the iPhone screen.

```
CGRect frame = MyButton.frame;

frame.origin.x = 10;
frame.origin.y = 10;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.1];
MyButton.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Does anyone know how i can generate a random number/position? Something like

```
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * (arc4random() % (10 - 1)); ?
```

But this is moving the button outside the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000
```

And get the float like:

double val = floorf(((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) * 100.0f);

More information here

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html

Answer (score 0):

Just make a random floating-point value between 0 and 1 like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060753/randomize-float-using-arc4random). Your current code will generate a value between 0 and 8 times the width of the screen, but only at integer multiples.