# random number generator objective c

Tags: c, random, floating-point, arc4random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a random float between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172421/how-to-generate-a-random-float-between-0-and-1)

I want to generate a random number between 0 and 1 (uniform distribution) and I use:

```
float x = arc4random_uniform(1);
```

However, this produces only 0.00000

I used

```
float y = arc4random() %11 * 0.1;
```

which returns a random number in the interval but I am not sure if it is uniform distribution.

Why isn't the first function working as expected?

Comment: You don't read the documentation, you don't accept answers, euh...

Comment: http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/arc4random_uniform/  It returns an int.

Answer (score 5):

> I use:

```
float x = arc4random_uniform(1);
```

> However, this produces only 0.00000

Of course it does. `arc4random_uniform()` returns a 32-bit unsigned integer. It does **not** return a `float`. What you're looking for is something like

```
#define RAND_PRECISION 1024

float x = arc4random_uniform(RAND_PRECISION) / (float)RAND_PRECISION;
```

Also,

> I am not sure if it is uniform distribution.

Since it isn't. Using the modulo (`%`) operator results in a non-uniform distribution.

Comment: Note that there's no way to give a truely uniform distribution on a floating point interval except one roughly of the form `[N,2N-N*FLT_EPSILON]` since, in general, floating point values are not uniformly spaced.

Comment: @R.. Of course, that's why I called the divisor `PRECISION`...

Comment: I did not downvote, but if your constant RAND_PRECISION was a power of two less than 2^23 (give or take a factor of 2, I am terrible at this particular kind of fencepost problem), your formula would at least give equiprobable evenly spaced values. Also, a compiler that tries to compile floating-point in a standard-conforming way has no choice but to compile `/ RAND_PRECISION` to a floating-point division. If it was a power of two, that could be optimized into a multiplication. Lastly, multiplying by `1.0f` is a strange way to convert an `int` to `float` (but the compiler should optimize it).

Comment: "I am terrible at this particular kind of fencepost problem" - I understand you. Mee too. Anyways, good suggestions and updated my answer accordingly, but that cast is really ugly.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: They're not even evenly spaced unless `RAND_PRECISION` is a power of two.

Comment: @R.. Yes, that is definitely what my first sentence was intended to mean.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, arc4random_uniform returns an integer, so using it with an upper bound of 1 won't produce what you want.

Here's the page on the arc4random functions:
http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/arc4random_uniform/

Comment: +1 but according to the manpage it returns an unsigned int

Comment: @fvu isn't an unsigned int an integer as well? Don't be nitpicky :)

Comment: Thanks for the +1, but the OP expected a float, therefore unsigned or signed is irrelevant in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x100000000
...
double val = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
```

Answer (score 0):

arc4random_uniform returns a number up to the upper bound you provide (e.g. arc4random_uniform(10) will return a number between 0 and 9). Due to that arc4random_uniform(1) should always return 0 (which is what you're seeing). If you want a random float you should see this answer:

[Generate a random float between 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172421/how-to-generate-a-random-float-between-0-and-1)