# Swift random float between 0 and 1

Tags: swift, random, arc4random, cgfloat

In Swift, I'm trying to get a random float between 0 and 1 but I can't seem to get the type conversions to work.

```
func randomCGFloat() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / UINT32_MAX
}
```

I'm getting a 'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'UInt8' error

Running Xcode 6.

Comment: Related: [Generate a random float between 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172421/generate-a-random-float-between-0-and-1)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Try initializing the divisor as a float as well, a la:

```
CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
```

Comment: Thanks,  I had tried casting the denominator with CGFloat and that wasn't working.  But it looks as if casting to a float first, and then to a CGFloat works.

Comment: No need to go via `Float` – just `CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)`.

Comment: @Joe_Schmoe if you don't go through Float / CGFloat the division is a small integer divided by a large integer, and will always return 0.

Comment: but in swift 4.2 just use: Float.random(in: 0..<1)

Answer (score 127):

This is extension for **random numbers**  of **Int, Double, Float, CGFloat**

**Swift 3 & 4 & 5 syntax**

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

// MARK: Int Extension

public extension Int {

    /// Returns a random Int point number between 0 and Int.max.
    static var random: Int {
        return Int.random(n: Int.max)
    }

    /// Random integer between 0 and n-1.
    ///
    /// - Parameter n:  Interval max
    /// - Returns:      Returns a random Int point number between 0 and n max
    static func random(n: Int) -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(n)))
    }

    ///  Random integer between min and max
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - min:    Interval minimun
    ///   - max:    Interval max
    /// - Returns:  Returns a random Int point number between 0 and n max
    static func random(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
        return Int.random(n: max - min + 1) + min

    }
}

// MARK: Double Extension

public extension Double {

    /// Returns a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.
    static var random: Double {
        return Double(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    /// Random double between 0 and n-1.
    ///
    /// - Parameter n:  Interval max
    /// - Returns:      Returns a random double point number between 0 and n max
    static func random(min: Double, max: Double) -> Double {
        return Double.random * (max - min) + min
    }
}

// MARK: Float Extension

public extension Float {

    /// Returns a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.
    static var random: Float {
        return Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    /// Random float between 0 and n-1.
    ///
    /// - Parameter n:  Interval max
    /// - Returns:      Returns a random float point number between 0 and n max
    static func random(min: Float, max: Float) -> Float {
        return Float.random * (max - min) + min
    }
}

// MARK: CGFloat Extension

public extension CGFloat {

    /// Randomly returns either 1.0 or -1.0.
    static var randomSign: CGFloat {
        return (arc4random_uniform(2) == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0
    }

    /// Returns a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.
    static var random: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float.random)
    }

    /// Random CGFloat between 0 and n-1.
    ///
    /// - Parameter n:  Interval max
    /// - Returns:      Returns a random CGFloat point number between 0 and n max
    static func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.random * (max - min) + min
    }
}
```

**Use :**

```
let randomNumDouble  = Double.random(min: 0.00, max: 23.50)
let randomNumInt     = Int.random(min: 56, max: 992)
let randomNumFloat   = Float.random(min: 6.98, max: 923.09)
let randomNumCGFloat = CGFloat.random(min: 6.98, max: 923.09)
```

Comment: In Swift 1.2 not working :( RandomNumber+Extensions.swift:5:5: Cannot invoke 'arc4random_buf' with an argument list of type '(inout T, UInt)'

Comment: @DaRk-_-D0G I'm trying to understand the math.  Why do you divide by 0xFFFFFFFF for the random() for Float and Double?

Comment: This is once again out of date for Swift 2

Comment: @EthanMick add Update for Swift 2 look ;)

Comment: " cannot call value of non-function type 'CGFloat' " error appears on trying to use  CGFloat.random(min:0.1, max:10.1)

Comment: Update for swift 3.1

Comment: No updating needed for Swift 4.

Comment: @Crystal Explains the use of 0xFFFFFFFF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479794/what-is-the-0xffffffff-doing-in-this-example

Comment: @YannickSteph With Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2, the line `return Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF` now gives a warning: `'4294967295' is not exactly representable as 'Float'; it becomes '4294967296'`. Any idea how to resolve that warning? I'm thinking to divide by `Float(UInt32.max)` instead.

Comment: @peacetype I look at this, I'll come back to you

Comment: `'public' modifier is redundant for static property declared in a public extension`
Seems like we should also remove the "inner" `public`s.

Comment: this is Done @d4Rk Thanks

Answer (score 52):

**swift 4.2 :**

```
let randomFloat = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
```

Answer (score 26):

Updating [Sandy Chapman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32866619/5501940) for Swift 3:

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound : FloatingPoint {
    public func random() -> Bound {
        let range = self.upperBound - self.lowerBound
        let randomValue = (Bound(arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX)) / Bound(UINT32_MAX)) * range + self.lowerBound
        return randomValue
    }
}
```

Now you can say stuff like `(-1.0...1.0).random()`.

**EDIT** I think today (Swift 4) I'd write that something like this:

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound : FloatingPoint {
    public func random() -> Bound {
        let max = UInt32.max
        return
            Bound(arc4random_uniform(max)) /
            Bound(max) *
            (upperBound - lowerBound) +
            lowerBound
    }
}
```

**NOTE** Swift 4.2 introduces native random number generation and all of this becomes moot.

Answer (score 16):

Here framework does a good job at generating random number data in Swift: 
https://github.com/thellimist/SwiftRandom/blob/master/SwiftRandom/Randoms.swift

```
public extension Int {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: Int = 0, _ upper: Int = 100) -> Int {
        return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
    }
}

public extension Double {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: Double = 0, _ upper: Double = 100) -> Double {
        return (Double(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (upper - lower) + lower
    }
}

public extension Float {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: Float = 0, _ upper: Float = 100) -> Float {
        return (Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (upper - lower) + lower
    }
}

public extension CGFloat {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: CGFloat = 0, _ upper: CGFloat = 1) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) * (upper - lower) + lower
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when compiling for `Generic iOS device`. The 0xffffffff doesn't fit inside an Int. Try this instead CGFloat(UInt32.max)

Answer (score 13):

Below is an extension on the `IntervalType` type for doing this:

```
extension IntervalType {
    public func random() -> Bound {
        let range = (self.end as! Double) - (self.start as! Double)
        let randomValue = (Double(arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX)) / Double(UINT32_MAX)) * range + (self.start as! Double)
        return randomValue as! Bound
    }
}
```

With this extension, you can use the interval syntax for generating an interval and then getting a random value in that interval:

```
(0.0...1.0).random()
```

**Addition**

If you're looking to do the same for `Int`s, then you can use the following extension on the `CollectionType` protocol:

```
extension CollectionType {
    public func random() -> Self._Element {
        if let startIndex = self.startIndex as? Int {
            let start = UInt32(startIndex)
            let end = UInt32(self.endIndex as! Int)
            return self[Int(arc4random_uniform(end - start) + start) as! Self.Index]
        }
        var generator = self.generate()
        var count = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count as! Int))
        while count > 0 {
            generator.next()
            count = count - 1
        }
        return generator.next() as! Self._Element
    }
}
```

`Int`s don't use the `IntervalType`. They use `Range` instead. The benefit of doing this on the `CollectionType` type is that it's automatically carried over to the `Dictionary` and `Array` types.

Examples:

```
(0...10).random()               // Ex: 6
["A", "B", "C"].random()        // Ex: "B"
["X":1, "Y":2, "Z":3].random()  // Ex: (.0: "Y", .1: 2)
```

Comment: how do we get this to work for Ints as well, not the original question, but seems a likely next step if we're extending IntervalType

Comment: @Joe_Schmoe : I've updated my answer with the details on using `.random()` on `Int`s, `Dictionary`s and `Array`s

Comment: I really like this solution, but I'm updating to include better generic practices

Comment: Broken in Swift 3.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 5**

```
let randomFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
```

Answer (score 6):

What jmduke suggested seems to work in Playground with a small change in the function:

```
func randomCGFloat() -> Float {
    return Float(arc4random()) /  Float(UInt32.max)
}
```

and the reason why from the swift doc and as noted by drewag: type conversion must be explicit, the example in the doc is:

```
let three = 3
let pointOneFourOneFiveNine = 0.14159
let pi = Double(three) + pointOneFourOneFiveNine
// pi equals 3.14159, and is inferred to be of type Double
```

Answer (score 3):

```
drand48()
```

In case you need [Double]. Between 0 and 1. That's all.

Comment: Elegant solution ‍ Don't forget about     `srand48(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))`

Answer (score 1):

*Based on YannickSteph's answer*

To make it work for any floating point type, like `Double`, `Float`, `CGFloat`, etc., you can make an extension for the `BinaryFloatingPoint` type:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {

    /// Returns a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.
    public static var random: Self {
        return Self(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF
    }

    /// Random double between 0 and n-1.
    ///
    /// - Parameter n:  Interval max
    /// - Returns:      Returns a random double point number between 0 and n max
    public static func random(min: Self, max: Self) -> Self {
        return Self.random * (max - min) + min
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Details

Xcode: 9.2, Swift 4

### Solution

```
extension BinaryInteger {

    static func rand(_ min: Self, _ max: Self) -> Self {
        let _min = min
        let difference = max+1 - _min
        return Self(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(difference))) + _min
    }
}

extension BinaryFloatingPoint {

    private func toInt() -> Int {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325962/4488252
        if let value = self as? CGFloat {
            return Int(value)
        }
        return Int(self)
    }

    static func rand(_ min: Self, _ max: Self, precision: Int) -> Self {

        if precision == 0 {
            let min = min.rounded(.down).toInt()
            let max = max.rounded(.down).toInt()
            return Self(Int.rand(min, max))
        }

        let delta = max - min
        let maxFloatPart = Self(pow(10.0, Double(precision)))
        let maxIntegerPart = (delta * maxFloatPart).rounded(.down).toInt()
        let randomValue = Int.rand(0, maxIntegerPart)
        let result = min + Self(randomValue)/maxFloatPart
        return Self((result*maxFloatPart).toInt())/maxFloatPart
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
print("\(Int.rand(1, 20))")
print("\(Float.rand(5.231233, 44.5, precision: 3))")
print("\(Double.rand(5.231233, 44.5, precision: 4))")
print("\(CGFloat.rand(5.231233, 44.5, precision: 6))")
```

### Full Sample

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

func run() {
    let min = 2.38945
    let max = 2.39865
    for _ in 0...100 {
        let precision = Int.rand(0, 5)
        print("Precision: \(precision)")
        floatSample(min: Float(min), max: Float(max), precision: precision)
        floatSample(min: Double(min), max: Double(max), precision: precision)
        floatSample(min: CGFloat(min), max: CGFloat(max), precision: precision)
        intSample(min: Int(1), max: Int(10000))
        print("")
    }
}

private func printResult<T: Comparable>(min: T, max: T, random: T) {
    let result = "\(T.self) rand[\(min), \(max)] = \(random)"
    print(result)
}

func floatSample<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(min: T, max: T, precision: Int) {
    printResult(min: min, max: max, random: T.rand(min, max, precision: precision))
}

func intSample<T: BinaryInteger>(min: T, max: T) {
    printResult(min: min, max: max, random: T.rand(min, max))
}
```

### Results

[image]