# Randomisation of Games in Swift

Tags: swift

I've been doing code samples in SpriteKit Game Programming in Swift 2, in this  [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/119815/sprite-kit-swift-2-tutorial-for-beginners)  tutorial. This tutorial explains other of the game functionality very comprehensively, like the spawning of monsters, instantiation of the `SKNodes`, to the point of already including verbose instructions through the comments in the Sample Project. However, the use of the random() function that I cannot really comprehend.

```
  func random() -> Float {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
  }

  func random(min min: Float, max: Float) -> Float {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
  }
```

First of all, is this merely an override of the random() function right? Isn't like the random() function returns half of the `arc4random()`? And then why do have to divide it by `0xFFFFFFFF`? What does that accomplish? And is the difference of the first and second function just the range and more randomisation?

Comment: the SECOND one is just an override that gives you a random between the given minimum and maximum you call it with.

Comment: i think the first is out of date, BTW.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32866619/294884

Comment: So you're saying the first and second functions are not overrides of the random() function in UIKit?

Comment: i think UIKit's "random()" returns an int.  the top one returns a float, so it's a different signature.  the bottom one has two args, so it's a different signature.  You probably wouldn't really describe that as an "override" these days.

Comment: Oh, thanks Sir Joe :)

Comment: @Programming_Duders CGFloat it is not the same as Float. Your random method wouldn't even compile btw

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that...just experimented...hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html):

> The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1

The first section of code in your question is the definition of a function *random()* that return a float pseudo-random number between 0 and 1.

This is obtained dividing the pseudo-random value for the maximum possible valued (0xFFFFFFFF is 2^32-1).

The second is an override of the previous one, that convert the range to your input one.

Comment: But what does it do when you call Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF?

Comment: As I said, it's dividing buy the maximum possible value, so it "converts" the value which is between 0 to 2^32-1 to a value between 0 and 1

Comment: Oh, I get it Sir Ale :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude! :)

Comment: I wasn't offended :) Tysm

Comment: But one last question, why does there have to be a "min min"

Comment: @Programming_Duders this makes it required to be specified when calling the method otherwise you would call it random(0, max: 1) instead of random(min: 0, max: 1)