# What is the 0xFFFFFFFF doing in this example?

Tags: swift, swift2

I understand that arc4random returns an unsigned integer up to (2^32)-1. In this scenario it it always gives a number between 0 and 1.

```
var x:UInt32 = (arc4random() / 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

How does the division by 0xFFFFFFFF cause the number to be between 0 - 1?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @TechBee: Their problem is that they don't understand how this works.

Comment: well said @BoltClock

Comment: I think this is just a way to say "initialize x with 0 but once in a blue moon make it 1 so that few years from now some poor developer will be pulling his hair out looking for a nasty bug"

Comment: it is so unlikely that it ever will yield a 1, that you can replace it with `var x = 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've stated,

> arc4random returns an unsigned integer up to (2^32)-1

0xFFFFFFFF is equal to (2^32)-1, which is the largest possible value of `arc4random()`. So the arithmetic expression `(arc4random() / 0xFFFFFFFF)` gives you a ratio that is always between 0 and 1 — and as this is an integer division, the result can only be between 0 and 1.

Comment: That is an integer division, the result can only be 0 or (seldomly) 1.

Comment: as Martin R said, the result is almost allways 0 with probability 1: 0xffffffff. By the way, are we talking about arc4random() ?

Comment: Do you mean the result must be between 0 - 1 and not either 0 or 1? The latter conflicts with your first statement of the result being a ratio.

Comment: @Hidden14: "between 0 and 1" inclusive. I should have been a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

to receive value between 0 and 1, the result must be floating point value

```
import Foundation
(1..<10).forEach { _ in
    let x: Double = (Double(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    print(x)
}
/*
 0.909680047749933
 0.539794033984606
 0.049406117305487
 0.644912529188421
 0.00758233550181201
 0.0036165844657497
 0.504160538898818
 0.879743074271768
 0.980051155663107
 */
```