# What is CGFloat.random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) of swift 2 in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

Im trying to generate CGFloat random but do not know how it is done in swift 3.
What is CGFloat.random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) of swift 2 equivalent in swift 3?
And where can I find changed swift functions from swift 2 to swift 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075467/2383604 use this:

```
public extension CGFloat {
    /// Randomly returns either 1.0 or -1.0.
    public static var randomSign:CGFloat {
        get {
            return (arc4random_uniform(2) == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0
        }
    }
    /// Returns a random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.
    public static var random:CGFloat {
        get {
            return CGFloat(arc4random())
        }
    }
    /**
     Create a random num CGFloat

     - parameter min: CGFloat
     - parameter max: CGFloat

     - returns: CGFloat random number
     */
    public static func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.random * (max - min) + min
    }
}

CGFloat.random
CGFloat.random(min: 0.1, max: 0.2)
```