# Can't extend generic struct for specific type

Tags: swift3

Wanted to toy with adding some sugar in Swift3. Basically, I wanted to be able to do something like:

```
let randomAdjust = (-10...10).random
```

To do that, I decided I would need to extend `ClosedRange`. But then found it would probably be even better for my case, I really just plan on doing Int's for now, to use `CountableClosedRange`. My latest of multiple attempts looked like:

```
extension CountableClosedRange where Bound == Int {
    var random:Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count) + 1)) + self.lowerBound
    }
}
```

But the playground complains:

```
error: same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Bound' non-generic
extension CountableClosedRange where Bound == Int {
```

I don't even know what it's telling me there.

Comment: You mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/40810305/341994

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712453/random-number-x-amount-till-x-amount-swift/34712601?s=1|0.2659#34712601

Comment: So what question do you want answered? I've shown you how to make a range `random` function; does that satisfy you or is the real goal to have me talk about the "I don't even know what it's telling me there" part?

Comment: I think the second. I continually get really frustrated trying to extend Protocols and even more Generics in Swift. So yes, I'm curious why I can't constrain Bound to Int there. Because the light bulb just hasn't lit for me yet. I like your more generic solution over in the other answer better. But it frustrates me that I couldn't even figure out how to write a poorer one. :/

Comment: Note that [concrete same-type requirements](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#concrete-same-type-requirements) will be supported in Swift 3.1.

Comment: @TravisGriggs If you do not say `@matt` in your reply to me, I can't "hear" you speaking. — Okay, I've written a little essay as an answer.

Comment: @Hamish, any idea when Swift 3.1 will hit a version of XCode?

Comment: @TravisGriggs It's intended to be released "spring of 2017" – https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-1-release-process/. Yesterday (Jan 16th) was the cut-off point for changes to be made, we're now in the "bake" period. So the release date is whenever they're finished "baking".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way this roadblock is commonly encountered is when attempting to extend Array. This is legal:

```
extension Array where Element : Comparable {
}
```

But this is illegal:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
}
```

The compiler complains:

> Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic

The problem is the use of `==` here in combination with Array's parameterized type Element, because Array is a generic *struct*.

One workaround with Array is to rise up the hierarchy of Array's inheritance to reach something that is not a generic struct:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Int {
}
```

That's legal because Sequence and Iterator are generic *protocols*.

Another solution, though, is to rise up the hierarchy from the target type, namely Int. If we can find a protocol to which Int conforms, then we can use the `:` operator instead of `==`. Well, there is one:

```
extension CountableClosedRange where Bound : Integer {
}
```

That's the real difference between our two attempts to implement `random` on a range. The reason your attempt hits a roadblock and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40810305/341994) doesn't is that you are using `==` whereas I am using `:`. I can do that because there's a protocol (FloatingPoint) to which Double conforms.

But, as you've been told, with luck all this trickery will soon be a thing of the past.

Comment: That example is discussed at the end of this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_extending_generics

Comment: And `extension Array where Element == Int` is now legal in Swift 3.1, available with Xcode 8.3 beta :)

Comment: @Hamish at last! Thx for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4, what you are attempting is now completely supported. Hooray!

```swift
extension Stack where Element: Equatable {
    func isTop(_ item: Element) -> Bool {
        guard let topItem = items.last else {
            return false
        }
        return topItem == item
    }
}
```

<sup>Example from Swift docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID553</sup>