# Swift - setting random UIColor not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm trying to set the scene background color to a random color on launch using the below code.

```
func randomColor() -> UIColor{
    //Generate between 0 to 1
    let red:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    let green:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    let blue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
    return UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.backgroundColor = randomColor()
    }
```

I'm using the code elsewhere in my program and its working as expected however when I try and set the scene background color with the same function it always loads the same green color. Any idea's why?

Comment: Use `arc4random_uniform()` instead. It won' require a random seed and will work as you expect.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050309/swift-random-float-between-0-and-1

Comment: @Mick bro can you replace code with `var red: CGFloat = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0
            // Or (recommended):
        var red: CGFloat = arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0` & let me know if work.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked.

Comment: the values should be between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these below function:

```
 func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
}

func colorOfView () -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:   self.random(),
                   green: self.random(),
                   blue:  self.random(),
                   alpha: 1.0)
}
```

In comment **Mukesh** is right.

**Reason:**

Many computer color palettes and Mac output devices expect RGB color components to be representable in 8 bit values, which, when expressed as integers, are in the range of 0 to 255.

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" way to generate a random number is `arc4random_uniform`, not `drand48` and I don't where did you find such a thing.

Instead of generating a random value for each component, why not just generate a single `Int` (between 0x0 and 0xffffff) and convert that to a color?

First, we generate the number:

```
let randomNumber = Int32(arc4random_uniform(16777216))
```

Next, we write an extension for `UIColor` that converts this number to a `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    public static func convertToColor(number: Int32) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(red: CGFloat((hex>>16)&0xFF) / 255.0, green: CGFloat((hex>>8)&0xFF) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(hex&0xFF) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Then we can call this method:

```
let randomColor = UIColor.convertToColor(number: randomNumber)
```