# Cast CGFloat to Int in extension BinaryFloatingPoint

Tags: swift, casting, int, cgfloat

> **FIXED IN SWIFT 4.2**

### Details

Xcode 9.2, Swift 4

### Code

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {

    func toInt() -> Int {
        // Eror if remove this block (I do not know why)
        //  if let value = self as? CGFloat {
        //      return Int(value)
        //  }
        return Int(self)
    }
}
```

### Error occurrence

```
let float: Float = 2.38945
print("Float: \(float.toInt())")        // No Error

let double = Double(float)
print("Double: \(double.toInt())")      // No Error

let cgfloat = CGFloat(float)
print("CGFloat(): \(Int(cgfloat))")     // No Error
print(".toInt(): \(cgfloat.toInt())")   // Thread 1: Fatal error: Conversion is not supported
```

[image]

### Question

Why

```
Int(cgfloat) // No Error
```

but

```
cgfloat.toInt() // Thread 1: Fatal error: Conversion
```

???

In both cases, the same type conversions `Int(value)` occur. My extension works with Float and Double types, but only with CGFloat error occurs.
Does it a Swift language bug?

Comment: Tht's odd, I thought `CGFloat` was an alias for `Double`/`Float` (depending on CPU bus size)

Comment: I thought so too. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, maybe post on https://bugs.swift.org and see what the core team thinks.

Comment: The logic for fully generic binary floating point to `Int` conversions was recently(ish) implemented in https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/11259 (previously it was limited to just the stdlib's floating point types, such as `Float` and `Double`). In Swift 4.1, your example runs without issue.

Comment: @Alexander It's actually a [fully fledged type of its own](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/CoreGraphics/CGFloat.swift.gyb#L25), but it does indeed wrap a `Float` or `Double` depending on architecture.

Comment: @Hamish Why is that? Why couldn't `CGFloat` just be implemented as a typealias, just like its `NativeType` member typealias?

Comment: @Alexander Good question! Presumably it's for architecture independent code, as e.g with a `typealias` you'd be able to freely pass a `CGFloat` to a `Double` on a 64 bit platform, but that won't compile on a 32 bit platform where `CGFloat` would be a `Float`. Having `CGFloat` as a separate type, which forces you to insert the necessary conversions e.g `Double(someCGFloat)`, lets the same code compile on both 32 bit and 64 bit platforms.

Comment: @Hamish Gah, I keep wishing there was a language feature to address this, like Haskell's [`newtype`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype)

Comment: @Alexander Yeah that would be really nice, the current situation of having to create a wrapper type and mirror the underlying type's entire API is far from ideal :/

Comment: @Sweeper, why the bounty on this one? Current versions of Swift support this as written; there's no longer a problem here.

Comment: I just wanted an explanation as to why this was not working before.