# How to make random float in swift with math operations

Tags: swift, random

Get an error when trying to use multiplication

```
var red1 : Float = ((random()%9)*30)/255;
```

Error says `Int` is not convertible to `Float`

I want to use this to make a float I can use to make a `UIColor`

Comment: Using `%` is a bad practice for generating random numbers, as it is biased. Better use a recommended way of generating a Float between 0 and 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765674/1033581

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random float between 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172421/generate-a-random-float-between-0-and-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var red1 = Float((random()%9)*30)/255`

You don't need the semicolon and red1 will be type inferred to a Float.

In swift 4.2: `var red1 = Float.random(in: startNumber...endNumber)`