# Random Double number in swift between 0 and 1

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to generate random double numbers between 0 and 1 but I'm getting always 0

```
func randFunct() -> Double {
     let randomInt = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1 // [1, 100]
     let randomDouble : Double = Double(randomInt/100)
     return randomDouble
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5172449/3141234

Comment: See also [Strange Swift numbers type casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting)

Comment: `let randomDouble = Double(randomInt)/100`

Comment: Why use `Double` when you seem to only want the result to 2 decimal places?

Comment: I want decimal numbers between 0 and 1

Comment: @Developer2012 - So why limit them to 2 decimal places?  And if you only want them to 2 decimals, why not use `Float` rather than `Double`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
extension Double {
    private static let arc4randomMax = Double(UInt32.max)

    static func random0to1() -> Double {
         return Double(arc4random()) / arc4randomMax
    }
}

print(Double.random0to1())
```

Comment: You should flag to close as a duplicate rather than repeating the already available answer that you, yourself, pointed out.

Comment: @pjs I wanted to help OP convert it to swift

Comment: This is nice for a `Float`, but suboptimal for `Double`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765674/1033581

Comment: @Cœur nice, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It solves my question:

```
    let randomDouble : Double = Double(arc4random()) / Double(UINT32_MAX) * abs(0 - 1) + min(0, 1)
```

Comment: You can keep your original code, just change the parenthesis to make it a Double before dividing by 100. BTW if you want a number from 0.0 to 1.0 just use arc4random_uniform(101) that would generate a number between 0-100. `var randomDouble: Double { return Double(arc4random_uniform(101))/100 }`

Comment: `* abs(0 - 1) + min(0, 1)`?

Comment: @Hamish == `* -1 + 0` == `* -1`? Yeah I'm confused, too. :p

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Equals `* 1 + 0`... so just plain useless lol :P

Comment: Ah yeah, it does an abs on the `-1`. lol I'm more confused now.