# get round numbers between 0 to 1

Tags: swift3

I have UISlider that produce  numbers between 0 to 1,

```
0.0590829
0.0643739
..
```

I want to get the rounded number between them, like:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
...
1.0
```

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172421/generate-a-random-float-between-0-and-1) (in c):

```
float x = arc4random() % 11 * 0.1;
```

but its not working on swift

```
var x = arc4random() % 11 * 0.1;
//error: binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt32' and 'Double'
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why people are voting this as "Too broad". Lack of effort shown, for sure.

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? Don't just ask people to do the work for you. You'll get more and better answers If you show what you've tried, and demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself. See [Ask]

Comment: @AshleyMills You are absolutely right, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Multiply by 10 to get values between 0.0 and 10.0
- round to remove the decimal
- divide by 10

Example:

```
let values = [0, 0.0643739, 0.590829, 0.72273, 1]

for value in values {
    print("\(value) -> \(round(value * 10) / 10)")
}

// 0.0 -> 0.0
// 0.0643739 -> 0.1
// 0.590829 -> 0.6
// 0.72273 -> 0.7
// 1.0 -> 1.0
```