# How to generate mxn matrix with randomly generated 0 and 1 with probability in C

Tags: c, random, probability

I wrote C program that defined a 2D matrix with m rows and n columns with random numbers (Either 0 or 1). The code is as following:

```
int i,j;
    int original_matrix[m][n];
    for (i=0; i<=m-1; i++){
        for (j=0; j<=n-1; j++){
            original_matrix[i][j] = rand() % 2;
        }
    }
```

It worked. For the next step, I want to create the matrix with a probability. For example, 1 is written into a cell with probability p and 0 is written with probability 1-p. Could you please share any ideas on this if you have?

Answer (score 3):

Since `rand()` gives you a value between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, you can get a value at particular perentage simply by choosing an appropriate threshold. For example, if `RAND_MAX` was `999`, 42% of all values would be expected to be less than `420`.

So you can use code like in the following complete program, to set up an appropriate threshold and test the distribution of your values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Get threshold (defaults to ~PI%), seed random numbers.

    double percent = (argc > 1) ? atof(argv[1]) : .0314159;
    int threshold = round(RAND_MAX * percent);
    srand(time(0));

    // Work out distribution (millions of samples).

    int below = 0, total = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        ++total;
        if (rand() < threshold) ++below;
    }

    // Output stats.

    printf("Using probability of %f, below was %d / %d, %f%%\n",
        percent, below, total, below * 100.0 / total);
}
```

Some sample runs, with varying desired probabilities:

```
Using probability of 0.031416, below was 31276 / 1000000, 3.127600%
Using probability of 0.031416, below was 31521 / 1000000, 3.152100%

Using probability of 0.421230, below was 420936 / 1000000, 42.093600%
Using probability of 0.421230, below was 421634 / 1000000, 42.163400%

Using probability of 0.175550, below was 175441 / 1000000, 17.544100%
Using probability of 0.175550, below was 176031 / 1000000, 17.603100%

Using probability of 0.980000, below was 979851 / 1000000, 97.985100%
Using probability of 0.980000, below was 980032 / 1000000, 98.003200%

Using probability of 0.000000, below was 0 / 1000000, 0.000000%
Using probability of 1.000000, below was 1000000 / 1000000, 100.000000%
```

---

So, the bottom line is: to acheive your desire of one having a probabilty `p` (a `double` value) and zero having the probability `1 - p`, you need the following:

```
srand(time(0));                               // done once, seed generator.
int threshold = round(RAND_MAX * p);          // done once.
int oneOrZero = (rand() < threshold) ? 1 : 0; // done for each cell.
```

---

Just keep in mind the limits of `rand()`, the difference between (for example) probabilities `0.0000000000` and `0.0000000001` will most likely be non-existent, unless `RAND_MAX` is large enough to make a difference. I doubt you'll be using probabilities that fine but I thought I'd better mention it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

`rand() % 2` gives you a probability of 0.5.

`p` is a float, so you'll look at [How to generate random float number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408990/how-to-generate-random-float-number-in-c) to generate a random value in a real range. The top answer gives us: `float x = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/a);`

We want `a` equal to 1 for probabilities. So, to get 0 with a probability of `p`, the formula is:

```
int zeroWithAProbabilityOfP = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX <= p;
```

Which can be also be written:

```
int zeroWithAProbabilityOfP = rand() <= p * RAND_MAX;
```

---

ps: if available, for precision reasons, you should favor [`arc4random()` or `arc4random_buf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765674/1033581) instead of `rand()`:

- `rand()` precision is 1 / 0x7FFFFFFF (on macOS)
- `arc4random()` precision is 1 / 0xFFFFFFFF (so twice better)

In that case, formula would be:

```
int zeroWithAProbabilityOfP = arc4random() <= p * UINT32_MAX;
```